# A: 周末愉快！ B: 你呢！ What does 你呢！mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "你呢！" mean? Can it be used as "You too", for example:

Person A: 周末愉快！

Person B: 你呢！

Google translate says that "你呢！" means You too, but [this dictionary](http://dictionary.pinpinchinese.com/definitions/s/%E4%BD%A0%E5%91%A2-nine) doesn't. My current guess is that it probably is appropriate, but is relatively informal.

Comment: don't think "你呢!" is an appropriate response to "周末愉快". Also I think "你呢" should be used as a question (followed by a question mark instead of exclamation), meaning "what about you?" e.g. "这周怎么样" "还可以，你呢?"

Comment: "你呢 ? " (how about you?) ; "你呢！" (you!)

Comment: 你呢？ what about you?,呢 is a modal particle used for a special type of question （用＂呢＂的疑问句）, see grammars, e.g."外国人实用汉语语法＂，用＂呢＂的疑问句（一）在独语句句尾加上助词＂呢＂表示疑问，询问人或事物在哪儿、怎么样的句子，是用＂呢＂的疑问句。它的基本格式是１。词---＂呢＂？例如：老马---呢？（我想看话剧， ）你---呢？钢笔---呢？２。偏正词组---＂呢＂？例如：你的请示报告---呢？（这位作家很年轻， ）那位---呢？

Comment: The sample dialog does not make sense to me. Where did you got it from?

Comment: It was an actual conversation

Answer (score 1):

你呢 translates to "how about you" and is usually followed by question mark not exclamation mark. 呢 is used as a way to express question.

Google translate sometimes does funny things. Cross check with other sources before trusting it.

If someone says 周末愉快! to you, reply to them with 周末愉快! is a safe bet. Or you can say Thank You.

Followup:

If the example conversation actually happened, it could be that when A says 周末愉快 and B interprets it as a question for how was/will be for your weekends. So B response with a nod and asking A about his/hers. Though even under this circumstance it still seems pretty strange. We don't usually speak in this manner.